# UDP proxy, how to maintain/reuse/purge pool of connected clients?

Tags: sockets, go, proxy, udp

I am creating a [UDP-proxy](https://github.com/nbari/UDP-proxy/tree/0.3.0) in [go](https://golang.org/), but while doing some load test using [iperf](https://iperf.fr/), I start to get this error:

```
socket: too many open files
```

After searching and testing, I found that if I create a pool using a [map](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action) of opening connections being the **key** [`*net.UDPAddr.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#UDPAddr) and the **value** an instance of [`UDP-proxy`](https://github.com/nbari/UDP-proxy/blob/0.3.0/proxy.go#L8-L15)  containing an  [`*net.UDPConn`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#UDPConn), I am available to reuse existing connection in case the client address is the same:

```
var clients   map[string]*UDPProxy.UDPProxy = make(map[string]*UDPProxy.UDPProxy)
```

This block of [code](https://github.com/nbari/UDP-proxy/blob/0.3.0/cmd/UDP-proxy/main.go#L74-L91) looks something like:

```
// wait for connections
for {
    n, clientAddr, err := conn.ReadFromUDP(buffer)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    counter++
    if *d {
        log.Printf("new connection from %s", clientAddr.String())
    }
    fmt.Printf("Connections: %d, clients: %d\n", counter, len(clients))
    proxy, found = clients[clientAddr.String()]
    if !found {
        // make new connection to remote server
        proxy = UDPProxy.New(conn, clientAddr, raddr_udp, *d)
        clients[clientAddr.String()] = proxy
    }
    go proxy.Start(buffer[0:n])
}
```

This seems to be working, but the problem I have now, is that I need find a way of expiring,cleaning the map when the client exists or is not using any more the proxy so that I could avoid having multiple unused connections.

Any idea how of could I improve this or even better, how could I replace totally the map, I don't know if [channels](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2) could be help full?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As UDP is a connectionless protocol, your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP thanks for the observation, I mean the pool of clients using the proxy, the issue is not related to how UDP protocol works, is more related of how to maintain a list of clients that will be using the Proxy to avoid reaching the limits ``too many open files``

Comment: Why? How can you possibly reach a limit when all you need is one UDP socket?

Comment: @EJP problem is not listening in one UDP socket, that works well, issue is that per each connection established I get an [IP:PORT](https://github.com/nbari/UDP-proxy/blob/0.3.0/cmd/UDP-proxy/main.go#L75) the one I need to proxy (a new connection to the remote server), If I am right iperf sends data in chunks using same port, therefore I can't just open new connections and need to find a way of how to handle existing clients.

Comment: You don't get 'connection(s) established', and you don't need to 'open a new connection' at all. I repeat that you only need one UDP socket for everything. Your question is based on a major misapprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating UDP proxies, you probably know that you have to come up with your own solution for deciding when to "terminate" the proxy session.  The session is just an abstraction when it comes to UDP - unless the UDPProxy package you're using has an established mechanism already.

Depending on why you are creating UDP proxies, it might be easy to arbitrarily cleanup connections ...

So if you know that a client is exiting, call the Close() method on the proxy (assuming there is one) and use delete on the map entry.

How to decide that a client is exiting is up to you.  Could use a slice as a FIFO, or pick one randomly, or try setting timers for each.

Comment: I should also have asked, what UDPProxy package are you using?

Comment: OP linked to their own UDP proxy code, which opens a new socket for every call to New

Comment: Oh yes.  So the package uses net.DialUDP() which returns a UDPConn pointer.  The UDPConn needs Close() called on it before totally removing the proxy object from the program's memory.  The OS will then be able to close the file descriptor.

Comment: @WeakPointer right, but since I am proxying I need to create a new ``UDPConn`` per every call thus I need to find a way of how to properly handle the clients to reuse/close session like you describe